# Commenting php tags

Tags: php

I got this code below from a tutorial I'm using to learn PHP.  I know that `//` is used to comment out code. In the first line of the code below, you see  `{// subject selected ?>`

Is the php tag  `?>`  not commented out by the `//` along with the `subject selected` text?

```
<?php if (!is_null($sel_subject)) {// subject selected ?>
<h2><?php echo   $sel_subject['menu_name'];?></h2>
<?php } elseif (!is_null($sel_page)) {// page selected ?>
<h2><?php echo $sel_page['menu_name']; ?></h2>
<?php } else { // nothing selected ?>
<h2>Select a subject or page to edit</h2>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @eisberg, I am glad he asked this as I never knew about it, now I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `?>` is not commented out.

Answer (score 4):

the BEST place to address such questions is [an official man page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php):

> The "one-line" comment styles only comment to the end of the line or the current block of PHP code, whichever comes first. This means that HTML code after // ... ?> or # ... ?> WILL be printed: ?> breaks out of PHP mode and returns to HTML mode, **and // or # cannot influence that.**

I can assure you that it's way more reliable source of knowledge than some volunteered help from some  enthusiast

Answer (score 1):

no `?>` are not commented out with the in line comment, where as the block comment they are.

http://codepad.org/YUhG2DTd

Example: The following `?>` does not get commented out.

```
<?php
\\?>

echo 'works';
?>
```

where as the following does get commented out.

```
<?php
/*
?>
*/

echo 'failed';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{// subject selected ?>
```

No, the `?>` is not commented. Because, that is not part of a php statement. That is a tag that apache uses to determine. Apache will send the contents enclosed by the tags to php and place the output from php in its output buffer.

Comment: apache has nothing to do with PHP tags. Go figure

Comment: @Col: apache or the web server. The webserver first gets the request. PHP is not a webserver. This is the basic. Apache (or the the websever, iis or whatever it is) decides whether to pipe to any program or not. Thats why, when you setup a server with php, you need to configure apache to work with php.

Comment: Yes, you need. But PHP tags has nothing to do with such configuring. -1

Comment: incorrect: Apache passes *the entire file* to the PHP interpreter when it detects a file/file type that has been registered accordingly. PHP is the one parsing PHP code out of the file according to its settings, not Apache